# Jquery setInterval works perfectly on Firefox , but did not work on IE8

Tags: jquery, firefox, internet-explorer-8, setinterval

i wrote a simple code to get content from PHP file and refresh it every 30 second .
it worked pretty on FireFox , but in IE8 only load contents one time !
can any body help me to fix it ?!

This is my Code :

```
<script>

var content;
var temp = "something";

    $.get('refresh.php', function(data) {
    content = data;
    })
  .success(function() {
      if (temp != content) {
          $("#success").fadeOut(2000, function () 
          {
              $("#success").html(content).fadeIn(2000); 
          }
          ); // end .fadeOut
      temp = content;
  }

  }) //end .success

  .error(function() { $("#success").html("error"); });

var refreshId = setInterval(function()
{
    $.get('refresh.php', function(data) {
    content = data;
    })
    .success(function() {
    if (temp != content) {
        $("#success").fadeOut(2000, function () 
        {
            $("#success").html(content).fadeIn(2000); 
        }
        ); // end .fadeOut
    temp = content;
    }

  }) //end .success

  .error(function() { $("#success").html("error"); })

}, 27000);
  </script>
```

and on PHP code i have this code :

```
echo rand();
```

Comment: Having duplicate copies of the same code is bad.  You should put the common code in a function and call it twice rather that copy/paste the same code.

Answer (score 1):

IE will be caching the ajax result. Put this before your $.get() calls:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid line breaks and comments in the mid method-chain; at best it's just ugly, at worst not all js engines will play ball. Also, you can move the declaration of `content` into the outer closure and cache the result of `$("#success")`.

```
var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
    var $success = $("#success");
    var content;
    $.get('refresh.php', function(data) {
        content = data;
    }).success(function() {
        if (temp != content) {
            $success.fadeOut(2000, function () {
                $success.html(content).fadeIn(2000); 
            });
            temp = content;
        }
    }).error(function() { $success.html("error"); });
}, 27000);
```

Answer (score 0):

IE cashing all get requests, try this:

```
$.get('refresh.php?'+ (new Date().getTime()), function(data) {
    content = data;
    })
...
```